# Service doesn't work in background

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

My service is like that:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(); 
private void ping() {
//My codes
scheduleNext();
}
     private void scheduleNext() {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ping();
                }
            }, 10000);
        }
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int x, int y) {
        mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
        ping();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

When app is not killed but not current program of the phone, this works but when i killed app, it doesn't work.
How can i make it run when app is killed? Thanks

Comment: It is not a service. It's just a handler and handler does not work when  the app is killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your Service to work even when the app is killed you have to make it a `ForegroundService`, and start it using `startForeground (int id, Notification notification)`. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) .